# PHP:MySQL what if we don't close the opened connections

Tags: php, mysql, html, connection, effects

In PHP + MySQL

This is:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("server","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("datbasename");
```

what we do to open a connection.

And this is:

```
mysql_close($conn);
```

what we do to close the connection.

- **WHAT** if we don't close the connections? What are going to be the effects?
- After what CONDITION the opened connections are automatically closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation for mysql_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php):

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution. See also freeing resources.

Answer (score 2):

With `mysql_connect` connection will close, when script is ended.

`mysql_pconnect` doesn't close connection.

If you work with more then 1 mysql servers, is necessery to control your closing connections, or create some persistance.

Answer (score 1):

In a small application nothing at all.  PHP is nice and cleans up memory/closes connections upon scripts execution completion.  If you are concerned about resources and utilization then I suggest closing your connections when you are finished using them.